# EBAY slideshow in Javascript tweak required

Tags: javascript

I have been searching for a slideshow script that works with Ebay, and found http://xlo.co/blog/web-development/javascript-image-fade?quip_thread=blog-post-19&quip_parent=76 this one that seemed to work ok. I wanted to add a third image to the slideshow and that's when things started going south. The following is the code that I altered from the original page to add the third image.

I've put  beside any of the code that I inserted. It works, however, the transitions stop working after the first image. If any one can help, it would be greatly appreaciated.

```
<div id="test">alpha</div>
<div id="slides" style="display: none;">
<div id="slide0" style="background-image: url('/ebay/images/image1.jpg'); width: 670px; height: 240px;">Content0</div>
<div id="slide1" style="background-image: url('/ebay/images/image1.jpg'); width: 670px; height: 240px;">Content1</div>
<!--ADDITION --><div id="slide2" style="background-image: url('/ebay/images/image1.jpg'); width: 670px; height: 240px;">Content2</div>
</div>

<div id="transition" style="width: 670px; height: 240px;">
<!--ADDITION --><div id="imageholder2" style="position: absolute;"></div>
<div id="imageholder1" style="position: absolute;"></div>
<div id="imageholder0" style="position: absolute;"></div>
<!--first last to avoid messing with z-indices-->
</div>
<!-- SCRIPT FUNCTION -->
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
//image transition
var interval = 3000;
var fadeTime = 10;
var currentImage;
var alpha = 100;
var images = new Array();
images[0]=document.getElementById('slide0');
images[1]=document.getElementById('slide1');
<!--ADDITION -->images[2]=document.getElementById('slide2');
var image0Holder = document.getElementById('imageholder0');;
var image1Holder = document.getElementById('imageholder1');;
<!--ADDITION -->var image2Holder = document.getElementById('imageholder2');;
var currentImageHolder = image0Holder;
var currentImage = 0;

var testId = document.getElementById('test');
image0Holder.appendChild(images[0]);
image1Holder.appendChild(images[1]);
<!--ADDITION -->image2Holder.appendChild(images[2]);

    function transition() {
            function fade() {   
                    if (alpha > 0) {
            alpha = alpha - 1;    
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = alpha;
            currentImageHolder.style.opacity = (alpha/100);
            currentImageHolder.style.MozOpacity = currentImageHolder.style.opacity;
            currentImageHolder.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity='+alpha+')';
                    }
                    else {
                        clearInterval(timer0);
                        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "xx";
                        if (currentImage == image0Holder) {                
                            image0Holder.style.zIndex = 0;
                            image1Holder.style.zIndex = 1;
                            <!--ADDITION -->image2Holder.style.zIndex = 2;
                            alpha = 100;
              currentImageHolder.style.opacity = (alpha/100);
              currentImageHolder.style.MozOpacity = currentImageHolder.style.opacity;
              currentImageHolder.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity='+alpha+')';                                                            
                            currentImageHolder = image1Holder;
                            image0Holder.removeChild(image0Holder.lastChild);
                            image0Holder.appendChild(images[currentImage]);                    
                        }                   
                        else {
                            image0Holder.style.zIndex = 2;
                            image1Holder.style.zIndex = 1; 
                            <!--ADDITION -->image2Holder.style.zIndex = 0;   
                            alpha = 100;
              currentImageHolder.style.opacity = (alpha/100);
              currentImageHolder.style.MozOpacity = currentImageHolder.style.opacity;
              currentImageHolder.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity='+alpha+')';
              currentImageHolder = image0Holder;
                            image1Holder.removeChild(image1Holder.lastChild);
                            image1Holder.appendChild(images[currentImage]);                            

                        }
                        currentImage = (currentImage+1)%images.length;
            timer1 = setTimeout(transition, interval);                        
                    }
            }
      timer0 = setInterval(fade, 20);
        }  
    timer1 = setTimeout(transition, interval);
// ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: This script seems to work only for two images. To my opinion that particular piece of code looks very ugly. You should consider rewriting it, so that you could use it with a arbitrary amount of images.